# Simple "skin" for GitLab or GitHub

Tags: web-apps, github

Not a skin like defining layout colors :-)

I would like to have a web app where I can define a template, have normal users use it, and then it gets put in the correct place on GitLab/GitHub. The idea is tho shield them from all the features of GitLab/GitHub.

Preferably, it would be a two-way thing, where you will be able to open "entries" (ie. files) and edit them also.

It could be a web app for adding and updating Jekyll blog entries linked directly to GitLab/GitHub.

It seems technically doable with proper API keys, and "sign in" using GitLab/GitHub.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, this is kinda broad. You want an interface? Please list the requirements and what you want to shield people from. Check out our [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Using the jekyl example...

To edit a page, you need to do git clone/pull, some editing, some git commit/push and so on. For the average user, that is difficult and error prone.

I would like an interface where the user can select a blog entry to update, edit it and click "save". All the git stuff is hidden and they don't need to know the mechanics of neither git nor pipelines.